# python binning sort considering the # of different values

Tags: python

How to efficiently change the list into the order of value of every element?

For example:

input1: [0,5,2,4,2] -> output1: [0,3,1,2,1]  # (there are totally 4 different values)

input2: [45,7,1024,45] -> output2: [1,0,2,1] # (3 different values)

input3: [5,1,2] -> output3: [2,0,1] # (3 different values)

I've tried np.digitize(array, bins) but the bins cannot be defined to satisfy this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pd.factorize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [0, 5, 2, 4, 2]

order_of_values, uniques = pd.factorize(lst, sort=True)
print(order_of_values)  # [0, 3, 1, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Daniel gave an answer to fit the exact output you wanted. Another option is `np.argsort` from numpy, which will give unique indexes.

```py
import numpy as np

lst = [0,5,2,4,2]
idx = np.argsort(lst)
print(idx)
# array([0, 2, 4, 3, 1])
```